# Filter with multiple dynamic user inputs.How to do it more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, filter, ecmascript-6

I have three inputs price that is coming from range input,name from text input and category from select.T tried using multiple if statements  and using three separate functions as arguments.Which is better and is there more readable and elegant way of doing this

```js
//I will put the variables and the html in case you want to see  them

const elements = e.target.elements;
const name = elements.name.value.trim().toLowerCase();
const price = parseInt(elements.price.value);
const category = elements.categories.value;
const filterPriceMaxValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".filter-price").max);

const filterAll = (products, category, name, price, filterPriceMaxValue) => {
    if (name && price < filterPriceMaxValue && category === '') {
        return products.filter(
            product => product.name === name && product.price <= price
        );
    } else if (name !== '' && price < filterPriceMaxValue) {
        return products.filter(
            product =>
            product.name === name &&
            product.price <= price &&
            product.category === category
        );
    } else if (name === '' && price < filterPriceMaxValue && category === '') {
        return products.filter(product => product.price <= price);
    } else if (name === '' && price === filterPriceMaxValue && category !== '') {
        return products.filter(product => product.category === category);
    } else if (name !== '' && price === filterPriceMaxValue) {
        return products.filter(product => product.name === name);
    } else if (name === '' && price < filterPriceMaxValue && category !== '') {
        return products.filter(
            product => product.price <= price && product.category === category
        );
    }
    return products;
};

//Or i tried using separate functions as arguments**strong text**
filterCategory(filterName(filterPrice(products, price, filterPriceMaxValue), name), category)
const filterName = (products, name) => {
    if (name !== '') {
        return products.filter(product => product.name === name)
    }
    return products
}
const filterPrice = (products, price, filterPriceMaxValue) => {
    if (price < filterPriceMaxValue) {
        return products.filter(product => product.price <= price);
    }
    return products;
};
const filterCategory = (products, category) => {
    if (category !== '') {
        return products.filter(product => product.category === category);
    }
    return products;
};
```

```html
<form class="filter-form">
    <select name="categories" class="filter-categories">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select a category -- </option>
    <option value="sport">sport</option>
    <option value="accessories">accessories</option>
    <option value="shoes">shoes</option>
    <option value="clothes">clothes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="filter-name" name="name" placeholder="product">
    <input type="range" value="1000" min="0" max="1000" name="price" class="filter-price">
    <label for="price" class="price-label">Price Range:<span class="price-span"></span></label>
    <button class="filter-btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: btw, `name` is a used property of `window`. maybe you take another name for it.

Comment: why do you need the max price? and what do you do with no category? you could add some data to get a working model.

Comment: I will use other variable than name and max price is to prevent unneeded filters.No category is empty string so with  no category it just compares price, name or both.Can yuo explain abouth the working model.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for every wanted filter part an use this functions for checking the products for filtering.

```
var elements = e.target.elements,
    fName = elements.name.value.trim().toLowerCase(),
    fPrice = +elements.price.value,
    fCategory = elements.categories.value,
    fMaxPrice = +document.querySelector(".filter-price").max,
    filters = [],
    products = [
        {
            category: 'sport',
            price: 42,
            name: 'shorts'
        },
        // more products
    ],
    filtered;

if (fName) {
    filters.push(o => o.name.includes(fName));
}
if (fCategory) {
    filters.push(o => o.category === fCategory);
}
if (!isNaN(fPrice)) {
    filters.push(o => o.price <= fPrice);
}
if (!isNaN(fMaxPrice)) {
    filters.push(o => o.price <= fMaxPrice);
}

filtered = products.filter(p => filters.every(f => f(p)));
```